# How can we make sqlite DataBase online so that to share data between Android client & server

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to develop an android app to get clients(Clients android device) current location and send it to the server (Admins Android Device). 
I want to use SQLite DB for it, 
How can I make database to be shared among various clients & a Admin.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to store database on online, you have use webservies to sync your current location to server.